# Adding dropdown and collapse functions to mobile menu

Tags: javascript

An issue that’s been bugging me for a while is that by default in the mobile menu of my theme, ALL menu items auto expand so it makes it hard to navigate if you have a lot of sub-menu items.

I’m trying to have my sub-menu items collapse with a drop-down arrow. Something that seems fairly simple but there are no options for adjust this in WordPress.

I managed to find some code in `Header.php` that you will find below

Any ideas how I can modify this code to have my sub-menu items collapse with a dropdown arrow?

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by Bootstrap:
[Bootstrap Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

or, You can also hide dropdowns in css:

```
li ul{
    display: none;
}
```

and show it on arrow click using jQuery:

```
$("li a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find("ul").toggle();
});
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/seyyedmojtaba72/pen/VOgmdE

Answer (score 0):

Pure js

```js
let arr=[...document.querySelectorAll(".toggle")];

arr.map(a=> a.onclick = e => {
    a.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
    a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML=='→' ? '&darr;' : '&rarr;'; 
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
.toggle { cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class='prett' href='#' >SubMenu A</a>
      <span class="toggle">&rarr;</span>
      <ul class='submenus hide'>
        <li><a href='#' >Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' >Dropdown 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='prett' href='#' >SubMenu B</a>
      <span class="toggle">&rarr;</span>
      <ul class='submenus hide'>
        <li><a href='#' >Dropdown 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' >Dropdown 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Back</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I had a hard time figuring out how to paste code without errors. Here is my code below. Any way to modify this code to have a collapsible drop down menu on mobile devices?

```html
<!– Toggle button for Main Navigation on mobile –>
<button class=”btn btn-primary header__navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up js-sticky-mobile-option” type=”button” data-toggle=”collapse” data-target=”#shaka-main-navigation”><i class=”fa fa-bars hamburger”></i> <span><?php esc_html_e( ‘MENU’ , ‘shaka-pt’ ); ?></span></button>
<!– Main Navigation –>
<nav class=”header__navigation collapse navbar-toggleable-md js-sticky-desktop-option” id=”shaka-main-navigation” aria-label=”<?php esc_html_e( ‘Main Menu’, ‘shaka-pt’ ); ?>”>
<?php
if ( has_nav_menu( ‘main-menu’ ) ) {
wp_nav_menu( array(
‘theme_location’ => ‘main-menu’,
‘container’ => false,
‘menu_class’ => ‘main-navigation js-main-nav js-dropdown’,
‘walker’ => new Aria_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
‘items_wrap’ => ‘<ul id=”%1$s” class=”%2$s” role=”menubar”>%3$s‘,
) );
}
?>
<?php
```